# Update multiple values of a dataframe using reactivevalues

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to update multiple values of my dataframe using reactivevalues. But my code works when I specify only value change. Below is my code,

```
values <- reactiveValues(df_data = NULL)

ipldata <- reactive({
        myfiles <- input$iplfile
        data <- read_excel(myfiles$datapath, 1, col_names = FALSE)
        data <- data.frame(data)
        data <- data[grep("esd", as.character(data[,1])),]
        data <- subset(data, data[,1]== input$modeltype)
        endrow <- grep(pattern = "Model/Extraction boundary information", as.character(data[,2]))
        data <- data[grep(pattern = 'Parameter|Instance Parameter', as.character(data[,2]))[1]:endrow,]
        data[is.na(data)]<- " "
        colnames(data) <- data[1,]
        data <- data[-1,-1]
        rownames(data) <- 1:nrow(data)
        last <- nrow(data)
        data <- data[-last,]
        data[!(is.na(data[,1])|data[,1]==" "),]
        values$df_data <- data
      })

  observeEvent(input$modeltype, {
    values$df_data <- ipldata()
    print(values$df_data)
  })

  
  #
  
  observeEvent(input$ChangeValues, {
  output$newvalue1 <- renderUI({
    data <- ipldata()
    textInput("newvalue1", paste0('New ',data[1,1]),data[1,5],'15%')
  })

  output$newvalue2 <- renderUI({
    data <- ipldata()
    textInput(paste0("newvalue2",data[2,1]), paste0('New ',data[2,1]),data[2,5],'15%')
  })

  output$newvalue3 <- renderUI({
    data <- ipldata()
    textInput(paste0("newvalue3",data[3,1]), paste0('New ',data[3,1]),data[3,5],'15%')
  })

  output$newvalue4 <- renderUI({
    data <- ipldata()
    textInput(paste0("newvalue4",data[4,1]), paste0('New ',data[4,1]),data[4,5],'15%')
  })
  
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$save, {
    isolate({
      
      values$df_data[1,5] <- input$newvalue1
      values$df_data[2,5] <- input$newvalue2
      # values$df_data[3,5] <- input$newvalue3
      # values$df_data[4,5] <- input$newvalue4
    
      })
  })

output$IPLTable <- renderTable(
                      values$df_data
                     #changedipldf
                     )
```

For simplicity I'm not attaching my ui code. In my observeevent with save button, I'm able to update when I use,

**Working code**

```
observeEvent(input$save, {
        isolate({
          
          values$df_data[1,5] <- input$newvalue1
          
        
          })
      })
```

**Non-working code**

```
observeEvent(input$save, {
    isolate({
      
      values$df_data[1,5] <- input$newvalue1
      values$df_data[2,5] <- input$newvalue2
      # values$df_data[3,5] <- input$newvalue3
      # values$df_data[4,5] <- input$newvalue4
    
      })
  })
```

The difference between the working observe event and non-working event is being the no of dataframe values that I'm trying to update before I click the save button. Can someone explain if reactivevalues are supposed to work for multiple updates in a dataframe or what am I doing wrong with my current code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the error in the render UI functions for values (2,3,4)

**Non-working code:**

```
output$newvalue2 <- renderUI({
    data <- ipldata()
    textInput(paste0("newvalue2",data[2,1]), paste0('New ',data[2,1]),data[2,5],'15%')
  })

  output$newvalue3 <- renderUI({
    data <- ipldata()
    textInput(paste0("newvalue3",data[3,1]), paste0('New ',data[3,1]),data[3,5],'15%')
  })

  output$newvalue4 <- renderUI({
    data <- ipldata()
    textInput(paste0("newvalue4",data[4,1]), paste0('New ',data[4,1]),data[4,5],'15%')
  })
```

**Working code:**

```
output$newvalue2 <- renderUI({
    data <- ipldata()
    textInput("newvalue2", paste0('New ',data[2,1]),data[2,5],'15%')
  })

  output$newvalue3 <- renderUI({
    data <- ipldata()
    textInput("newvalue3", paste0('New ',data[3,1]),data[3,5],'15%')
  })

  output$newvalue4 <- renderUI({
    data <- ipldata()
    textInput("newvalue4", paste0('New ',data[4,1]),data[4,5],'15%')
  })
```

The textInput "id" values were not correct for the code posted in the Q.